# Flutter Widget testing with HttpClient

Tags: flutter, http, dart, widget-test-flutter

I am trying to write a widget test for a screen, not the main app. It's my first time writing a widget test and I couldn't find a proper solution for the issue.
I don't know how to write a proper test for this one. I tried to write a simple widget test and it end up giving me an error as below
"Warning: At least one test in this suite creates an HttpClient. When
running a test suite that uses TestWidgetsFlutterBinding, all HTTP
requests will return status code 400, and no network request will
actually be made. Any test expecting a real network connection and
status code will fail.
To test code that needs an HttpClient, provide your own HttpClient
implementation to the code under test, so that your test can
consistently provide a testable response to the code under test."
I have just started learning it please help me.
NOTE: my test was just writing a basic test for finding Text widgets.

```
class BookingDetails extends StatefulWidget {
final booking;
BookingDetails(this.booking);
@override
_BookingDetailsState createState() => _BookingDetailsState();
}

class _BookingDetailsState extends State<BookingDetails>
with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

Row _buildTeacherInfo(Map<String, dynamic> teacherData) {
return teacherData != null
    ? Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 53,
            backgroundColor: MyColors.primary,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 50.0,
              backgroundImage: teacherData['user']['img_url'] == null ||
                      teacherData['user']['img_url'] == ''
                  ? AssetImage('assets/images/placeholder_avatar.png')
                  : NetworkImage(teacherData['user']['img_url']),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 20.0),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      '${teacherData['user']['first_name']} ',
                      style: AppStyles.textHeader1Style,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '${teacherData['user']['last_name']}',
                      style: AppStyles.textHeader1Style,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //View Profile method
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: MyColors.primary,
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25))),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.next_plan_outlined),
                    SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                    Text('VIEW PROFILE'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )
    : Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 48,
            backgroundColor: MyColors.primary,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 45.0,
              backgroundImage:
                  AssetImage('assets/images/placeholder_avatar.png'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 20.0),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Teacher allocation in progress',
              style: AppStyles.textHeader1Style,
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
  }

Widget _buildBookingDetails(
Map<String, dynamic> booking,
List<dynamic> campusData, // one campus' data is an array for some reason.
Map<String, dynamic> instData,
) {
return Expanded(
  child: Scrollbar(
    child: ListView(
      children: [
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.location_on),
          title: Text(
            '${campusData[0]['address_line1']},'
            ' ${campusData[0]['suburb']}, '
            '${campusData[0]['state']} ${campusData[0]['postcode']} ',
            style: AppStyles.textHeader3Style,
          ),
        ),
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
super.build(context);
return FutureBuilder(
  future: Future.wait([_teacherData, _campusData, _classData, _instData]),
  builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.connectionState ==
          ConnectionState.waiting
      ? MyLoadingScreen(message: 'Loading booking data, please wait...')
      : snapshot.hasData
          ? SafeArea(
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _buildTeacherInfo(snapshot.data[0]),
                      Divider(color: MyColors.dividerColor),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),

                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Divider(
                        color: MyColors.primary,
                        thickness: 1,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      _buildBookingDetails(
                        widget.booking,
                        snapshot.data[1],
                        snapshot.data[3],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Divider(
                        color: MyColors.primary,
                        thickness: 1,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Center(
                        child: widget.booking['cancelled_by_inst'] == true
                            ? Text(
                                'Canceled',
                                style: AppStyles.textHeader3StyleBold,
                              )
                            : widget.booking['teacher_id'] == null
                                ? Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Teacher Allocation in Progress',
                                      style: AppStyles.textHeader3StyleBold,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : null,
                      ),
                     }
```

Comment: When you post a snippet, it would be helpful if it is a minimal representation of the problem, i.e. leaving out each and everything which is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Tried to do my best to give an insight into the screen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have reduced your code to the following minimal version, to be able to execute it:

`snippet.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'api.dart';

class BookingDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, String> booking;
  BookingDetails(this.booking);
  @override
  _BookingDetailsState createState() => _BookingDetailsState();
}

class _BookingDetailsState extends State<BookingDetails> {
  late Future _campusData;

  Future<dynamic> _fetchCampusData() async {
    var campusID = widget.booking['campus_id'];
    if (campusID != null) {
      var response = await api.getCampusByID(campusID);
      return json.decode(response.body);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _campusData = _fetchCampusData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _campusData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Text('Displaying data');
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('An error occurred.');
          } else {
            return const Text('Loading...');
          }
        }

    );
  }
}
```

`api.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

final _ApiClient api = _ApiClient();

class _ApiClient {
  Future<http.Response> getCampusByID(String id) async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://run.mocky.io/v3/49c23ebc-c107-4dae-b1c6-5d325b8f8b58');
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
      throw "An error occurred";
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

Here is a widget test which reproduces the error which you described:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:widget_test/snippet.dart';

void main() {

  testWidgets('Should test widget with http call', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    var booking = <String, String>{
      'campus_id': '2f4fccd2-e199-4989-bad3-d8c48e66a15e'
    };

    await tester.pumpWidget(TestApp(BookingDetails(booking)));
    expect(find.text('Loading...'), findsOneWidget);

    await tester.pump();
    expect(find.text('Displaying data'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}

class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  TestApp(this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the error message, for a reference:

```
Test failed. See exception logs above.
The test description was: Should test widget with http call

Warning: At least one test in this suite creates an HttpClient. When
running a test suite that uses TestWidgetsFlutterBinding, all HTTP
requests will return status code 400, and no network request will
actually be made. Any test expecting a real network connection and
status code will fail.
To test code that needs an HttpClient, provide your own HttpClient
implementation to the code under test, so that your test can
consistently provide a testable response to the code under test.
```

##### Solution

The error tells you what the problem is: you must not execute HTTP calls in the widget tests. So you need to mock that HTTP call out, so that the mock is called instead of the real HTTP call. There are many options with which you can do that, e.g. using the [mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) package.

Here a possible solution using the [nock](https://pub.dev/packages/nock) package which simulates an HTTP response at the HTTP level.

`pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  nock: ^1.1.2
```

Widget test:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:nock/nock.dart';
import 'package:widget_test/snippet.dart';

void main() {
  setUpAll(nock.init);

  setUp(() {
    nock.cleanAll();
  });

  testWidgets('Should test widget with http call', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    nock('https://run.mocky.io')
        .get('/v3/49c23ebc-c107-4dae-b1c6-5d325b8f8b58')
      .reply(200, json.encode('{"id": "49c23ebc-c107-4dae-b1c6-5d325b8f8b58", "name": "Example campus" }'));

    var booking = <String, String>{
      'campus_id': '2f4fccd2-e199-4989-bad3-d8c48e66a15e'
    };

    await tester.pumpWidget(TestApp(BookingDetails(booking)));
    expect(find.text('Loading...'), findsOneWidget);

    await tester.pump();
    expect(find.text('Displaying data'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}

class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  TestApp(this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Janux, it helped a lot to learn but one question why does it sometimes gives me an error about the widget tree when I want to test a particular one?

Comment: Without seeing the details of that error, I can't tell. However, I supposes that this problem is not related to the question how to create tests for widgets using HTTP calls. So, I suggest to you to do some further investigations and create a new question if necessary.

Comment: I solved the issue thanks Janux.

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me while writing an integration test.
When I was signing in to my app, the API was giving 400 and the same error was thrown as mentioned below:

```
Warning: At least one test in this suite creates an HttpClient. When
running a test suite that uses TestWidgetsFlutterBinding, all HTTP
requests will return status code 400, and no network request will
actually be made. Any test expecting a real network connection and
status code will fail.
To test code that needs an HttpClient, provide your own HttpClient
implementation to the code under test, so that your test can
consistently provide a testable response to the code under test.
```

I've fixed this in the way mentioned below:

I've added `IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` in the `main()` function of the integration test.

For Example: Before the solution was implemented, the code looks like:

```
void main() {
    testWidgets('Sign In Test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    // MY TEST HERE
  });
}
```

And after I've implemented the solution, the code looks like:

```
void main() {
    IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    testWidgets('Sign In Test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    // MY TEST HERE
  });
}
```

After implementing this, when I was tapping on the sign in button, the application was actually calling the API against the button and the response was received successfully.

Don't forget to `import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';`

Make sure to call `await tester.pumpAndSettle();` to settle all the frames required by the button (Widget) or any microtask scheduled to get settled!

Hope it helps...

Comment: This worked fine for me however received some warning https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83929